# Aptana Plugin Installation: Adding features

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, installation, aptana

I have installed Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1), then I installed Aptana IDE from the update site, followed by Eclipse PDT from the update site as well. (In that order)

I now want to add the additional Aptana features, which are available in the Aptana Standalone installation as "Install New Software". So in the standalone mode, we would get that installation screen with options for jQuery support, ExtJS support, Dojo, Ruby and the works basically.

Since I have a plugin installation of Aptana in Eclipse 3.7.1, how do I access that Aptana feature installation screen? If not, how do I install all the Aptana specific features?

Answer (score 1):

The "Install New Aptana Feature" menu is only available in Aptana Studio 2.0.  If you have installed Studio 3 plugins, the menu won't be there.  However, Studio 3 includes Ruby/PHP/Python support by default, and you could add additional JavaScript library support such as jQuery using the instruction here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is at all relevant to the Aptana Studio 3.x plugin. Instead, you install jQuery support using the "Rubles" (aka "Bundles"). After installing the Aptana Studio 3.x plugin, go to the new "Commands" menu and find the "Bundle Development" sub-menu and follow it to "Install Bundle", i.e.

Commands > Bundle Development > Install Bundle

jQuery should be among the choices you are offered in the pop-up. Assuming you have Git installed, Aptana should open up a terminal view in Eclipse and run a Git clone of the bundle into your UserFolder\Aptana Bundles (Windows) or your ~/Documents/Aptana Bundles (Mac / Linux). You will then want to use the Javascript "Source Editor" in order to be able to use the extra features added by the bundle.

Hope that helps some of the others baffled by how this all works. I'm by no means "expert" in this yet, but I was similarly perplexed by the steps needed to take to get the Aptana Studio plugin to do very much "useful".

Comment: Having to use a particular editor was a key point for me, easy to miss that.